# ASP.NET MVC3 SQL database row delete issue

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

If created a website using MVC3 and have a database attached to it.
They are all linked together. I have a table for countries, table for states, table for cities. Now when I delete for example a country, the states and cities attached to it still remain in the database. I cant see them in the controllers list, but they do show up in the dropdown when choosing for example a state when creating a city. How do I fix this ?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is a very vague question. Please share your code and database model. Are there foreign key constraints between Countries, Cities, and States? If so, you may be able to use ON DELETE CASCADE for the foreign keys.

Comment: THis is explained in http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use foreign key relationships set them to **ON DELETE CASCADE** as shown in the screenshot.  That way when you delete a country, it will automatically delete the states, cities, etc that depend on it.

[image]

Or manually loop through and delete them yourself starting with cities, then their states and then the parent country.

You should be using foreign keys though..

Comment: Thanks, I was using foreign keys but I think I dont have that option selected!

Comment: +1 more. I have been using code first so long I never realized mssql finally got SetNull cascade option. I know it's been in ANSI sql for a while, and have always wondered when it would come to sql server.

Comment: THis is explained in http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application